# How to extract .sql file that seems to be a .zip

Tags: sql, zip

I have received a file from a customer. The file is said to be

> SQL code (application/sql)

However, this has turned out to be wrong: nothing could open it. It turns out it was secretely a .zip file. By renaming it to '.zip' and manually extracting it I was able to get the files contained in it. I would like to do a similar process in python.

So far I've renamed the file:

```
file_name_zip = file_name.replace('.sql', '.zip')
os.rename(file_name, file_name_zip)
```

And I've tried extracting it:

```
zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(file_name_zip, 'r')
zip_ref.extractall(extracted_file)
```

However, this failed because

> zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

I've googled, and apparently this can sometimes be fixed using:

```
zip_file_name_2 = zip_file_name.replace('.zip', '2.zip')
os.system(f'zip -FF {zip_file_name} --out {zip_file_name_2}')
```

This required me to put in a bunch of settings, which I wasn't able to figure out. There must be a better way to go about this.

Does anybody know how to parse such an .sql file?

Comment: what extension does it have currently?

Comment: It currently has .sql, I've decided to try and fix it using pg_restore

Comment: instead of zipfile.Zipfile can you try gzip.GzipFile